# Basic HTTP Authentication with python 3.2 (urllib.request)

Tags: asp.net, python-3.x, basic-authentication

This is my first post with this account, and Ive been struggling for the last week to get this to work, so I hope someone can help me get this working.

Im trying to pull some data from https://api.connect2field.com/ but its rejecting all of my authentication attempts from python (not from a browser though).
The code Im using

```
import urllib.request as url
import urllib.error as urlerror
urlp = 'https://api.connect2field.com/api/Login.aspx'

# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = url.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='Connect2Field API',
                          uri=urlp,
                          user='*****',
                          passwd='*****')
opener = url.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
url.install_opener(opener)
try:
    f = url.urlopen(urlp)
    print (f.read())
except urlerror.HTTPError as e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            if e.code != 401:
                print ('We got another error')
                print (e.code)
        else:
            print (e.headers)
```

Im pretty sure the code is doing everything right, which makes me think that maybe theres another authentication step that ASP.net requires. Does anybody have any experience with ASP.Net's authentication protocol?

Im gonna be checking this post throughout the day, so I can post more info if required.

**Edit:** Ive also tried running my script against a basic http auth server running at home, and it authenticates, so Im pretty sure the request is set up properly.

Comment: Could you maybe give the error you are getting? Especially the headers that are send back? Also, did you try to inspect with Wireshark what headers are really sent?

Comment: Ive submitted a bug request to python. It turns out that python silently fails if the realm isnt quoted in the auth request header. The fix includes changing  

'realm=(["\'])(.*?)\\2', re.I)
to
'realm=(["\']?)(["\']*)\\2', re.I)  

in AbstractBasicAuthHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IIS is set up to do basic authentication, ASP.NET will be most probably be configured to use windows authentication.

As you have said that authentication works  via browser, so the best bet for you is to use tool such as fiddler to capture request/response when connecting via browser and also when connecting via your code. Compare them to troubleshoot the issue.

For example, I remember a case where the web site first requested authentication credentials and then re-directed to different url which prompted for different credentials.

Comment: At the moment it looks like thanks to my request they are making some changes to the way they accept authentication. When the site comes back up, ill try capture my requests and post any information I can get. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: python and urllib.request struggle to work with fiddler. Ive tried manually adding a proxy using proxy_handler and with FancyURLOpener, but cant get a capture from fiddler. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @bantroth, try another tool such as Firebug (add-on to Firefox) or Wireshark!

Comment: Thanks Vinay, turns out the the auth header was malformed (didnt include quotes around the realm) Using fiddler helped a lot

Comment: python wasnt accepting the system proxy so I had to manually add a proxy into my script then fiddler worked like a charm